# TouchableOpacity and onPress for Icons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, native-base

I am trying to use onPress for icons. For this, I thought of using TouchableOpacity but nothing happens when I click on the icon. I don't see any console logs.

I also tried wrapping the icon in an additional View but that doesn't work either.

```
const criteriaList = [
    "Nur Frauen",
    "Freunde Zweiten Grades",
]


export const FilterCriteriaList: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.horizontalLine} />
          {criteriaList.map((item: string) => (
        <View key={item}>
            <View style={styles.criteriaRow}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.iconContainer} onPress={()=>console.log('dhjksds')}>
            <Icon style={styles.icon} name="circle-thin" color="#31C283" size={moderateScale(20)}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.horizontalLine} />
         </View>
      ))}
      </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  criteriaRow: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      paddingLeft: moderateScale(25),
  },
  horizontalLine: {
    width: '100%',
    height: moderateScale(1),
    backgroundColor: '#E0E0E0',
  },
  text: {
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(15),
    paddingBottom: moderateScale(15),
    marginBottom: moderateScale(15),
    paddingTop: moderateScale(15),
  },
  icon: {
      paddingTop: moderateScale(12),
  },
  iconContainer: {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
  }
});
```

[image]

It looks like this and I click in the middle of the circle icon.

What else can I try?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the icon is overwriting the touchable component. There is no height and width provided to the touchable opacity. So it has hidden behind the icon. Provide some height and width in the styles of the TouchableOpacity. It should work.

Add some background color to the TouchableOpacity while debugging, so that you will get a clear view on the TouchableOpacity layout.

Comment: Adding background-color is for debugging purposes. The suggested workaround is to add some width and height to the touchable opacity.

Comment: I just saw the background color pic. Have you added it to Touchable Opacity? Can you please update your code also to get a clear picture?

Comment: It looks strange. Somewhat TouchableOpacity has hidden behind some view. Try adding zIndex to the component. iconContainer: {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      zIndex: 1
  }

Comment: Can you say from where you have import touchableopacity?

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/dpmUu3!s4 created a snack with the exact same styling. Oddly, it works here but not in my simulator. Any ideas why that might be? I even tried adding a touchableOpacity to the Text and whole row. Still, I am unable to click on them. @DhevendhiranM

Comment: from 'react-native-gesture-handler'; @mainak

Comment: Change that from 'react-native'

Comment: Ok.. let me try from myself

Comment: @DhevendhiranM adding zIndex to the whole View which contains this component worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this... woking for me.. I've just changed console to alert and some css

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.horizontalLine} />
      {criteriaList.map((item, index) => (
        <View key={index}>
          <View style={styles.criteriaRow}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.iconContainer}
              onPress={() => alert("ff")}
            >
              <Icon
            style={styles.icon}
            name="circle-thin"
            color="#31C283"
            size={20}
          />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.horizontalLine} />
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  criteriaRow: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    padding: 25,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  horizontalLine: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#E0E0E0",
  },
  text: {
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    marginBottom: 15,
    paddingTop: 15,
  },
  icon: {
    padding: 12,
  },
  iconContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
});
```

Comment: Could you specify what changes you have made to the styling? I only see this added ``` alignItems: "center"```It still doesn't work for me. The problem isn't alert or log. I can simply not 'click' or 'press' on the icon for now

Comment: That style is not mandatory here... you can ignore it. But I don't see anything not to work... Can you change your icon part to just a view with only height and width.. inside touchable

Comment: I tried that earlier but it didn't work. Adding a zIndex to the whole view that contains this component worked for me now.